# Please identify this figure/build

Tags: set-identification, minifigure-identification

***[image: strong text]***

I would like to know from what set this figure/build is? It looks like a tiger/human hybrid.

Answer (score 12):

That is [Tiger, Standing (Tygurah)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=tygurah&idColor=29#T=C&C=29) from [7411 set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7411-1)

[image]